# Expressing sums of complex exponential functions with no imaginary parts

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I am trying to express this signal function as a sum of complex exponential signals

$$s(t) = 10 + 20 \cos(200\pi t+\pi 4) + 10 \cos(500\pi t).$$

I know that $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$
and the complex exponential signal takes the form $e^{ix}$.

So far, I've been able to write $10=10e^{i\cdot 0}$
How can I express the rest of the signal sum of signals' complex exponential forms if there are no imaginary sine parts in the equation?

Comment: It might prove fruitful to recall

$$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Comment: I just started learning Euler’s identity and am not aware of that equation. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply decompose each sine|cosine using:

$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x) \\ e^{-ix}=\cos(x)-i\sin(x) \\ $$

$$\cos(x)={e^{ix}+e^{-ix} \over 2} \\ \sin(x)={e^{ix}-e^{-ix} \over 2i} \\ $$

Hence:

$$ s(t)=10+20\cos(200\pi t+4\pi)+10\cos(500\pi t) \\
=10+20{e^{i200\pi t+i4\pi}+e^{-i 200\pi t+i4\pi} \over 2}+10{e^{i 500\pi t}+e^{-i 500\pi t} \over 2} \\
=10+10e^{i200\pi t+i4\pi}+10e^{-i 200\pi t+i4\pi} +5e^{i 500\pi t}+5e^{-i 500\pi t}  \\
$$